# How to open port in Docker container with sh?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port, ethereum

I'm having private Ethereum network running in Docker container. Since i'm on PoW i need to generate DAG and it takes about 10 minutes. I need to signal to host that it's finished somehow so i decided to open a port 5555. So in my init script i'm trying to do it:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  eth_miner:
    image: ethereum/client-go:v1.7.3
    ports:
      - "8545:8545"
      - "5555:5555" # required?
    volumes:
      - ${DATA_DIR}:/root/.ethereum
      - ${HASH_DIR}:/root/.ethash
      - ${GENESIS_FILE}:/opt/genesis.json
      - ${INIT_FILE}:/opt/init-script.sh
    entrypoint: sh /opt/init-script.sh
    command: --rpc --rpcaddr=0.0.0.0 --rpcapi=db,eth,net,web3,personal --rpccorsdomain "*" --nodiscover --cache=512 --verbosity=4 --mine --minerthreads=3 --networkid 15 --etherbase="${ETHERBASE}" --gasprice=${GASPRICE}
```

init-script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# check for genesis file
if [ ! -f /root/.ethereum/.init ]; then
    echo "running 'geth init /opt/genesis.json' ..."
    geth init /opt/genesis.json
    touch /root/.ethereum/.init
    echo "... done"
fi

# check for DAG generated
if [ ! -f /root/.ethash/full-R23-0000000000000000 ]; then
    echo "running 'geth makedag 10000 /root/.ethash' ..."
    geth makedag 10000 /root/.ethash
    echo "... done"
fi

echo "opening port 5555 to show DAG is ready "
nc -l 5555 &
echo "... done"

echo "running 'geth $@'"
geth "$@"
```

If i leave `5555:5555` mapping in `docker-compose.yml` then it's opened right after started and can't work as signal:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                  NAMES
808a5453bf57        ethereum/client-go:v1.7.3   "sh /opt/init-script…"   4 seconds ago       Up 11 seconds       0.0.0.0:5555->5555/tcp, 8546/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8545->8545/tcp, 30303/tcp, 30303-30304/udp   7f8680be_eth_miner_1
```

even if it's not opened (logged to docker container):

```
/ # netstat -lntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:39593        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42033           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::30303                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::8545                 :::*                    LISTEN      
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:56580        0.0.0.0:*
```

If i remove it from `docker-compose.yml` then i obviously can't access it in test:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No internal port '5555' for container 'eth_miner': Suppliers.memoize(com.palantir.docker.compose.connection.Container$$Lambda$46/1692550316@5ac2447d)
```

So is it possible to use this approach?

UPDATE: if it makes sense 'ethereum/client-go' Docker image is [based](https://hub.docker.com/r/ethereum/client-go/~/dockerfile/) on `golang:1.10-alpine as builder` image

Comment: What you do want is communication from the container to the host?

Comment: I dont think there is an easy way to do this. Can't you wrape everythings in containers?

Comment: At the best, I think you can share an unix socket then communicate throught this socket

Comment: If it is possible , you can try extending the image and expose required port (5555) ?

Comment: port 5555 is already exposed (see `docker-compose.yml`)

Comment: With the port published, it will show in netstat, but you still can't connect to it until the container starts listening. How are you testing the port being up?

Comment: @fly2matrix exposing a port is documentation, it does not change the behavior of docker.

Comment: Not exactly -- docker-compose.yml exposing port here is helping you to map port while creating containers -- which is equal to `docker run -p`. So port exposing is controlled thourgh docker-image definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to create you own docker image by extending the parent one.
Create your own Dockerfile

```
FROM ethereum/client-go:v1.7.3
EXPOSE 5555
```

Build it and generate a new docker image

```
#>docker build -t custom-client-go -t xyz/custom-client-go .
```

Push it to your docker registry (xyz profile under docker-hub) using docker push.

```
#>docker push xyz/custom-client-go
```

and then update docker-compose.yml (image-name - > xyz/custom-client-go

Comment: did not test it as i've solved it by parsing docker output, but looks good.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use an approach based on files. As you've seen docker daemon open this port even if there is no listener in the container.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  eth_miner:
    image: ethereum/client-go:v1.7.3
    ports:
      - "8545:8545"

    volumes:
      - /var/run/geth:/var/run/geth
      - ${DATA_DIR}:/root/.ethereum
      - ${HASH_DIR}:/root/.ethash
      - ${GENESIS_FILE}:/opt/genesis.json
      - ${INIT_FILE}:/opt/init-script.sh
    entrypoint: sh /opt/init-script.sh
    command: --rpc --rpcaddr=0.0.0.0 --rpcapi=db,eth,net,web3,personal --rpccorsdomain "*" --nodiscover --cache=512 --verbosity=4 --mine --minerthreads=3 --networkid 15 --etherbase="${ETHERBASE}" --gasprice=${GASPRICE}
```

init-script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# check for genesis file
if [ ! -f /root/.ethereum/.init ]; then
    echo "running 'geth init /opt/genesis.json' ..."
    geth init /opt/genesis.json
    touch /root/.ethereum/.init
    echo "... done"
fi

# check for DAG generated
if [ ! -f /root/.ethash/full-R23-0000000000000000 ]; then
    echo "running 'geth makedag 10000 /root/.ethash' ..."
    geth makedag 10000 /root/.ethash
    echo "... done"
fi

echo "Writing file to show DAG is ready "
touch /var/run/geth/ready
echo "... done"

# Trap signals to remove /var/run/geth/ready on exit
trap "rm /var/run/geth/ready TERM; exit $?" TERM
trap "rm /var/run/geth/ready EXIT; exit $?" EXIT

echo "running 'geth $@'"
geth "$@"
```

Comment: i like your approach though it's not an answer to my question (so +1). Actually I've solved it by parsing docker output for the token.